# elasticsearch: reindexing an index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index which a few fields as keyword type. I need ot have these fields as text instead now.

Going through [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#:%7E:text=Except%20for%20supported%20mapping%20parameters%2C%20you%20can%E2%80%99t%20change%20the%20mapping%20or%20field%20type%20of%20an%20existing%20field.%20Changing%20an%20existing%20field%20could%20invalidate%20data%20that%E2%80%99s%20already%20indexed.), it seems to be not possible.

Documentation instead asks to create a new index and reindex it with documents from older index.

Can I keep new index name same as old one? Won't it cause issues during reindexing process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, you need to reindex to an index with a different name. One thing you could do, is to (1) reindex to e.g. `original_index_name_v2`, (2) create an [index alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/indices-aliases.html) named `original_index_name` catching `original_index_name_*` indices, (3) delete the original index. This way, next time you'll need to change the mapping, you don't need to change the index name but just keep querying the same alias